# Export data to multiple table from XLSX using Angular js

Tags: javascript, angular, excel, typescript, xlsx

I was trying to export data from two tables into one excel sheet, I already export two table in to two sheets, how can I get all data in to sheet.

```
  exportAsExcel(excelObj: ExcelExport,excelObjHeader: ExcelExport): void {
let wb: XLSX.WorkBook;
let header = excelObj.header

const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSXUtils.json_to_sheet(excelObj.data);
const ws1: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSXUtils.json_to_sheet(excelObjHeader.data);


wb = XLSXUtils.book_new();
 XLSXUtils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, excelObj.sheetName);
 XLSXUtils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws1, excelObjHeader.sheetName);

     
writeFile(wb, `${excelObj.fileName.trim()}${this.fileExtension}`);}
```

[image]

[image]

**I am try to ger this format**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) module and I remodelled my problem using that module.

```
 exportExcelReport(result)
  {
    this.sName = 'tsetName';
    this.excelFileName = 'Teat_Excel.xlsx';
    this.cols =['ID','ItemCode','ItemName','Quantity','Price','LineTotal']
    var excelItem = [];
    
    for (let index = 0; index < result.Details.length; index++) {
      const element = result.Details[index].ID;
      console.log(element);
      excelItem.push({
       
       ID: result.Details[index].ID,
       ItemCode: result.Details[index].ItemCode,
       ItemName: result.Details[index].ItemName,
       Quantity: result.Details[index].Quantity,
       Price: result.Details[index].Price,
       LineTotal: result.Details[index].LineTotal

   }); }
    
    this.data=excelItem
   
    var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    workbook.creator = 'Web';
    workbook.lastModifiedBy ='Web';
    workbook.created = new Date();
    workbook.modified = new Date();
    workbook.addWorksheet(this.sName, { views: [{ state: 'frozen', ySplit: 4, activeCell: 'A1', showGridLines: true }] })
    var sheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
    var head1 = ["Document No.",result.Code ,  "   Status" , result.Name, "   Date Range",this.datePipe.transform( result.FromDate,'yyyy/mm/dd') +" - "+this.datePipe.transform( result.ToDate,'yyyy/mm/dd') ];
    sheet.addRow("");
    sheet.addRow(head1);
    sheet.addRow("");
    sheet.getRow(4).values = this.cols;
    sheet.columns = [
      { key: 'ID' },
      { key: 'ItemCode' },
      { key: 'ItemName' },
      { key: 'Quantity' },
      { key: 'Price' },
      { key: 'LineTotal' },
    ];
    sheet.addRows(this.data);
    workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then(data => {
      var blob = new Blob([data], { type: this.blobType });
      var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.href = url;
      a.download = this.excelFileName;
      a.click();
      
     
    });
  }
```

[refrense1](https://embed.plnkr.co/kaJEMNKXoKpilHRbY7hW/)
[refrense2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8zBkHIqooI)